# I checked closing tags and brackets.It's telling me the return is not in a function I don't know how to fix it

Tags: reactjs, jsx

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hRlm4.png)

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Card, CardImg, CardImgOverlay, CardTitle } from "reactstrap";
import CampsiteInfo from "./CampsiteinfoComponent";

class Directory extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedCampsite: null,
    };
  }
  onCampsiteSelect(campsite) {
    this.setState({ selectedCampsite: campsite });
  }

  render() {
    const directory = this.props.campsites.map((campsite) => {
      return (
        <div key={campsite.id} className="col-md-5 m-1">
          <Card onClick={() => this.onCampsiteSelect(campsite)}>
            <CardImg width="100%" src={campsite.image} alt={campsite.name} />
            <CardImgOverlay>
              <CardTitle>{campsite.name}</CardTitle>
            </CardImgOverlay>
          </Card>
        </div>
      );
    });

    return (
      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
          {directory}
          <CampsiteInfo campsite={this.state.selectedCampsite} />
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
return <div className="row">{this.renderCampsite(this.props.campsite)}</div>;

export default Directory;
```

Comment: The `return` in the second line from the bottom: which function is it in?

Comment: I believe it's suppose to go in the render.

Answer (score 0):

delete this. It's outside the component.

`return <div className="row">{this.renderCampsite(this.props.campsite)}</div>;`

EDIT:

From your comment, if you need to add that part to the components, I would add it inside the directory object:

```
const directory = this.props.campsites.map((campsite) => {
  return (
    <div key={campsite.id} className="col-md-5 m-1">
      <Card onClick={() => this.onCampsiteSelect(campsite)}>
        <CardImg width="100%" src={campsite.image} alt={campsite.name} />
        <CardImgOverlay>
          <CardTitle>{campsite.name}</CardTitle>
          <div className="row">{this.renderCampsite(this.props.campsite)}</div>
        </CardImgOverlay>
      </Card>
    </div>
  );
});
```

But based on the error the function `this.renderCampsite` doesn't seem to exist in the component. Maybe need to add that first.

Comment: I tried that and I get another error. saying (this.renderCampsite is not a function)

Comment: how would I put that return statement in the render, where it could work is what I want to know...

Comment: Edited my answer.